# Storing inputs to a macro in an array (C)

Tags: c, arrays, macros

I have defined a macros as shown below.

```
#define NAME_OUT(name_in)  PRE_##name_in##_POST
```

I would like to iterate through this macro using names i have defined in a table/array.  Is it possible to do something like this?  If so how would I do this?

NOTE:  The above example is for illustrative purposes only :)

Comment: Iterate though a macro? What do you mean? Anyway, I highly doubt you can. The macro "names" exist only before the preprocessing stage.

Comment: The [boost preprocessor library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) can perform some types of iteration using the preprocessor. It doesn't seem to fit what you're doing directly, but it's possible you could change your approach to use the library. We really need more detail in your question to give you useful information.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking, but it sounds a lot like you are looking for the "X macros" pattern:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// list of data
#define NAME_LIST \
  X(foo)          \
  X(bar)          \
  X(hello)        \
  X(world)


// whatever you are actually using these for, maybe an enum or variable names?
typedef enum  
{
  // temporarily define the meaning of "X" for all data in the list:
  #define X(name) PRE_##name##_POST,
    NAME_LIST
  #undef X // always undef when done
} whatever_t;


// helper macro to print the name of the enum    
#define STRINGIFY(str) #str


int main()
{
  #define X(name) printf("%s %d\n", STRINGIFY(PRE_##name##_POST), PRE_##name##_POST);
    NAME_LIST
  #undef X
}
```

Output:

```
PRE_foo_POST 0
PRE_bar_POST 1
PRE_hello_POST 2
PRE_world_POST 3
```